# Convert between angular and linear momenta?

Tags: angular-momentum, momentum, moment-of-inertia

Answers to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/244523/conversion-of-angular-momentum-to-linear-momentum-in-free-space) say that angular and linear momenta are independent and cannot influence each other. However, I propose the free-space "ring launcher" illustrated below as a counter-example.

## Ring Launcher

[image]

The red and blue rings have the same mass (red + red = blue) and are counter-rotating.  The small green capsule on the edge is a payload to be launched.  The large green capsule near the hub is a counterweight for the payload.  To launch the payload, the red and blue rings start spinning.  When the desired velocity is reached, the payload is released, and the counterweight simultaneously moves to the center.  I claim that the ring will trade angular momentum for linear momentum of the payload, and will not experience a negative linear momentum (it will stay in place, to a reasonably high approximation, dependent on how quickly the counterweight can be moved).

Unfortunately, my calculus and mechanics are not strong enough to compute solutions for this problem.  If my conclusion is wrong, I would be happy to look at an explanation.

Now, the reason I believe that the ring will not obtain a net linear momentum is because the imbalance of forces when the payload is released will constantly rotate around the COM.  Furthermore, thought experiments on the inverse scenario also convince me.

## Ring Capture

Imagine the ring as above, but instead of launching a payload, there is a payload shaped like a C-clamp right next to the ring.  It is fixed relative to the ring axis.  At some point, it clamps, and "joins" the ring.  Since there is no linear momentum, I expect the ring to slow its rotation by some amount proportional to the change in the angular moment of inertia.  Because the ring is now asymmetrical, I expect it to precess about its COM, but otherwise not gain any linear momentum.  Hopefully, this part is uncontroversial.

In the next scenario, we have not one, but two rings, situated next to each other, coaxially.  We have a payload which is attached to one ring, which is rotating at $v_{slow}$, but which can clamp onto the other ring, rotating at $v_{fast}$.  At some point, the payload unclamps from the slow ring and clamps onto the fast ring simultaneously.  This time, the payload has both angular and linear momentum, but I expect the fast ring to respond in essentially the same way as before (in fact, I claim that there exists some value for $v_{slow}$ and $v_{fast}$ which makes the end result identical in both cases).

Finally, I consider a third scenario where the payload arrives ballistically in a linear trajectory (the mirror of the launcher scenario).  Again, the ring "captures" the payload, alters its angular momentum, but experiences no net change in its linear momentum, instead precessing about its COM.  I argue that in the limit where $\delta t \rightarrow 0$, the second and third scenarios are identical (for suitable velocity values, of course).

Where did I go wrong?

## [EDIT] Spinning Rod

The simplest I can reduce the scenario is to imagine a rod spinning in space.  A point mass approaches on a linear trajectory exactly tangent to the circle traced by the outer edge of the rod, at the same velocity as the rod is rotating. It is also in phase with the rod such that it attaches to it at the tangent point.  Does the rod+mass acquire the linear momentum of the point mass or no?

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to say in your other examples but your floating rod one doesn't work. Even if you hit the rod at the side, the stationary rod will both move forward and rotate. The linear momentum of the center of mass of the rotating rod will be equal to the linear momentum lost by the other rod.

Comment: @BrainStrokePatient I updated the example, but I agree that if they remain disconnected, and merely collide, that the momenta are conserved.

Comment: Yes, rod+mass does acquire linear momentum of the point mass.

Comment: Angular and translational momentum are not independent quantities but **do** influence each other. They are both part of the description of the line-of-action of momentum in space. That is the magnitude, direction and location of momentum.

Answer (score 0):

To address this question let me first provide some necessary background.

[image: momentum and angular momentum]

This image offers a representation both of Newton's first law, and an area law.

An object, released to move freely, will move along the equally spaced points ABCDE in equal intervals of time.

Additionally you have the following option:
Taking an arbitrary point S that moves in inertial motion, and then the object will sweep out equal areas in equal intervals of time.

Next I compare what form of freedom is available.

For attribution of linear momentum there is freedom to choose any inertial coordinate system; conservation of linear momentum will hold good.

For attribution of this instance of a *law of areas* there is freedom to choose any inertial coordinate system; conservation of swept out area will hold good.

Note especially that with this particular *attribution* of momentum and law of areas the two are *independent from each other.*

In the usual application of physics the above sense of angular momentum is hardly ever used. Far more common is the case you are referring to: multiple objects (two objects at minimum) that are in one form or another *bound* to each other.

The simplest instance of such a bound-to-each-other case is two point masses, connected by a massless rod. In that very common case you want to use the Common Center of Mass of the two point masses as the *point of reference* of the angular momentum of that bound system.

Once you've opted for that specific point of reference the angular momentum of that bound system is a given; now the Common Center of Mass is acting as an exclusive reference of motion.

When committed to a *single* reference of motion the instantaneous linear momentum that you attribute and the angular momentum that you attribute are *connected* quantities.

So it depends on context.

When you are free to choose any member of the equivalence class of inertial coordinate systems as the reference of motion then linear momentum and angular momentum are indepentent.

What you describe is a specific context where the two are not independent.

Comment: The area law is helpful, but I think that the momenta are conserved after all, even in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it some more, I have realized that my mistake was not varying the relative masses through their entire range.  Suppose that the payload is large compared to the ring (like, orders of magnitude more massive).  In this scenario, the ring will essentially spin around the payload (because the barycenter will likely be inside of it), and when it releases, the ring will go flying off.  When the ring and the payload are exactly the same mass, we are reduced to the good ol' two point masses connected by a massless rod.  When they spin, they have non-zero angular momentum, but zero linear momentum.  When the rod disconnects, they go flying off in opposite directions, with zero net linear momentum.  However, the angular momentum is preserved by the fact that their trajectories are not collinear (they are offset by the length of the rod).

Indeed, we can run the picture backwards and show that the angular momentum of non-collinear motion of objects can be converted to the angular momentum of circular motion by connecting them when they approach suitably close.